# how do i return http tags in map function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, renderscript, array-map, recharts

I'm trying to build a dynamic bar chart which has many levels ..  So i used map function to generate the the chart . i do console logging the var  and stuffs, its working properly. But the return of the tag doesn't render . i try simple div {`<div>Hey</div>`} but it also doesn't render .
This is my code ,

```
import React from 'react';
import {BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} from 'recharts';


export const LocalBarChart =({config, data})=>{

    //data :-  [{name: 'X Axis Name', levelOneName: levelOneValue, levelTwoName: levelTwoValue} , {name: 'X Axis Name', levelOneName: levelOneValue, levelTwoName: levelTwoValue}];

    //config :-  {numberOfLevel: (1-10) , COLORS : ['#0088FE', '#00C49F', '#FFBB28', '#FF8042']}; // 0 means full filled piechart, 0<x<50 ->liner circle

    const COLORS = config.COLORS;
    let keysArray=Object.keys(data[0]);

    return(
        <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="6 0"/>
            <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
            <YAxis/>
            <Tooltip/>
            <Legend />


            {  data.map((e, i) => {

                if(i===0){
                    console.log(e);
                    keysArray.map((datas,indexs)=>{
                        if(datas!=="name"){
                            console.log(indexs)
                            console.log(datas)
                            return (
                                <Bar dataKey={datas} stackId="a" fill={COLORS[indexs]} />
                            );

                        }
                    })
                }


            }) }


        {/* <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
       <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" />
       <Bar dataKey={keysArray[1]} stackId="a" fill={COLORS[0]} />    */}
        </BarChart>
    );


}
```

Please help me to figure it out .. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `return` before `keysArray.map((datas,indexs)=>{`
you need to return inside map in order to get array.

currently you are getting array of null values.

from your code - you'll be getting 2D array. is that what you want !

Comment: actual i did answer before that.. anyways never mind

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from map as

```
return(
    <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
        margin={{top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="6 0"/>
        <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
        <YAxis/>
        <Tooltip/>
        <Legend />


        {  data.map((e, i) => {

            if(i===0){
                console.log(e);
                return keysArray.map((datas,indexs)=>{
                    if(datas!=="name"){
                        console.log(indexs)
                        console.log(datas)
                        return (
                            <Bar dataKey={datas} stackId="a" fill={COLORS[indexs]} />
                        );

                    }
                })
            }


        }) }


    {/* <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
   <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" />
   <Bar dataKey={keysArray[1]} stackId="a" fill={COLORS[0]} />    */}
    </BarChart>
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: ` {
                keysArray.map((d, i) =>(
                    (d!=="name") ? <Bar dataKey={d} stackId="a" fill={COLORS[i-1]} />: '') 
                )
            } `  this also worked

Comment: glad to help, yes in case of arrow function return is implicit